# C# Invoking method with params argument

Tags: c#

I'm running into an issue with calling Invoke on a method in C# that makes use of the params keyword. It seems like the Invoke method does not properly handle variable arguments the same as calling the method directly.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prog = new Program();
        prog.run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // case 1: works as expected
        method("a", "b", "c");

        // case 2: works as expected
        method("a", new object[] { "b", "c" });

        // case 3: works as expected
        GetType().GetMethod("method").Invoke(this, new object[] { "a", new object[] { "b", "c" } });

        // case 4: throws exception, but similar to case 1
        GetType().GetMethod("method").Invoke(this, new object[] { "a", "b", "c" });

    }

    public void method(string a, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        foreach (var arg in args)
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to use case 4, but it is throwing a TargetParameterCountException exception. Is this just a limitation with reflection in C#?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, this is just me telling you to not create a new instance of program just to call the run method. better syntax would either be `this.run();` or even just `run();`

Comment: The passing of multiple parameters as an array using the `params` keyword is a trick of the compiler - it actually changes the call of case 1 to be `method("a", new object[] { "b", "c" })`. When calling `Invoke`, you must do the same manually.

Comment: I belive (could be wrong), that the second parameter of invoke, is actually sending params to the function. Meaning: `new object[] { "a", new object[] { "b", "c" } }`, in this context "a" is a param a to your `method` and `"b", "c"` are `args`. Now, with the 4th case, with this knowledge, you can see, that you're passing `new object[] { "a", "b", "c" }`, however you're passing it in the place, where you `string a` param should be, resulting in your error. If you change your code to this: `new object[] { "Random placeholder text", new object[] { "a", "b", "c" } }`, I believe it should run fine.

Comment: @TDiblik Yes, that would be case 2.

Comment: See the C# Language Reference for [parameter arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#14625-parameter-arrays)

Comment: @JoshHeaps: Neither of those is correct; THERE IS NO `this` object when the program starts running (as a result the entrypoint `Main` is required to be `static`)

Comment: @BenVoigt you're right about `this.run();` not being valid. If `run` were a static method, he wouldn't need to create an instance of program though. It would be better to do this inside of the run method: `typeof(Program).GetMethod("method").Invoke(new Program(), new object[] { "a", new object[] { "b", "c" } });`

Comment: @JoshHeaps: That wouldn't be any better.  He wants to call `method()` 4 times, all on a single instance of `Program`.  He could create that instance just once at the top of a static method and call `prog.method()` twice and pass `prog` to `Invoke` twice instead of `this`, but that would be doing exactly what `Main()` already does, except more repetition.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this just a limitation with reflection in C#?

Yes, although "limitation" isn't really a fair way to describe it.  You wouldn't look at dough that a baker is rolling out and be able to tell whether it's going to become a bun for a premium hamburger or a "dollar menu" one.  You're simply at the wrong level of abstraction.

Reflection allows you to see the structure of the class and its members after the C# compiler has processed it.  You'll find that a lot of things are different, not only do things like `await` and `yield` break methods apart into helper classes and multiple helper functions, but things like function overload selection and coercion of actual parameters to the formal parameter types have to be done by hand.  Default arguments get filled in, named parameters cause reordering.  None of that is part of the function you are calling, it's all done at compile-time and if you want to bypass the compiler you have to do it.